# best way to get records created today with Ecto Phoenix?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

Coming from Rails Active Record I was wondering how can i actually fetch records which are created today.

In Rails we can do it like this

```
User.where(created_at:Date.today.beginning_of_day..Date.today.end_of_day)
```

or much concise

```
scope :created_today, ->(date = Date.today) { where(created_at: date..date.end_of_day) }

User.created_today
```

what would be best way to implement same thing with Ecto??

Comment: What timezone do you want to calculate "today" in? UTC, current system's default, or a specific one?

Comment: current system's default

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use the [Timex](https://hexdocs.pm/timex/getting-started.html) Library.

Using this library you could do something like this:

```
date = DateTime.today |> Timex.datetime

query = from m in Model, where: m.inserted_at >= ^Timex.beginning_of_day(date), where: m.inserted_at <= ^Timex.end_of_day(date)

Repo.all(query)
```

Comment: To expand on this a bit for those looking to handle a given timezone in this situation and your datetime column is stored in UTC, one way is something like this:

    date = date |> Timex.Timezone.convert("America/Chicago")
    query = from m in Model,
      where: m.inserted_at >= ^Timex.Timezone.convert(
              Timex.beginning_of_day(date), "UTC"),
      where: m.inserted_at <= ^Timex.Timezone.convert(
              Timex.end_of_day(date), "UTC")